# How to rewrite the google sheet query formula to combine multiple sheets with custom column

Tags: google-sheets

I have a query formula that I am trying to identify to name the query data.

I am able to pull the correct data but when trying to add a column I am getting a REF error.

```
=QUERY({{'ref1'!A2:B,"name1"};{'ref2'!A2:B,"name2"}}, "Select * where Col1 is not null")
```

The ref is same for all, only the sheet name is renamed.

Here's a sample file:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cJ_EzqdupLVtsGPE9h9tmqbZ25bgYmi5X92D8OZkE2o/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula to try:

```
=QUERY({{index(if(len('ref1'!A2:A),"ref1",)),'ref1'!A2:B};{index(if(len('ref2'!A2:A),"ref2",)),'ref2'!A2:B}},"where Col1 is not null")
```